# For Loop printing squares without multiplication

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to produce this output without multiplication:

```
81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289
```

I produced that with this for loop:

```
    for (int k = 9; k <=17; k++){

        System.out.print( k * k +" ");
    }
```

But again, I am trying to create a for loop or nested for loops producing the same output without multiplication.

```
Pseudocode:
Start with value 81
Increment by 19
On the second loop add ++3 to the 19 value
```

I have not been able to get to the second for loop stage I am confused. Any feedback or push in the right direction is appreciated.

```
/**
 * Created on 8/28/15.
 * Following Reges, Stuart, and Martin Stepp. Building Java Programs: A Back to Basics Approach. 3rd Edition.
 * Chapter 2 Self-Check Problems & Exercises
 */
public class Ch2_SelfCheckProblems {

          public static void main(String[] args) {
        ex2();    
    }

    public static void ex2(){
        for (int i = 81; i <= 289; i=i+19){
                /*for (int j = 1; j >=( i - 81 );j++){
//                    System.out.print(j+" ");
//                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }*/
//            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
//        System.out.println();

/*        for (int k = 9; k <=17; k++){

            System.out.print( k * k +" ");
        }*/
        for (int k = 81; k <=289; k++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++){
                k = k + 8;
            }
            System.out.print( k +" ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use addition instead of multiplication. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int k = 9; k <= 17; k++) {
        int t = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            t += k;
        }
        System.out.print(t + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output is (the requested)

```
81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289
```

Another option would be [`Math.pow(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int k = 9; k <= 17; k++) {
        System.out.print((int) Math.pow(k, 2) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

for the same output. Finally, from [@mschauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556061/mschauer)'s comments below, you could also use something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int r = 64, k = 9; k < 18; k++) {
        r += k + k - 1;
        System.out.printf("%d ", r);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to use the fact that n ^ 2 = (n - 1) ^ 2 + (n - 1) + n .

Comment: Is it possible to complete without declaring `int t`? and/or with one for loop?

Comment: @mschauer With a `for` loop (or nested `for` loop)?

Comment: @phillipsK `Math.pow` doesn't use `int t`.

Comment: Without classes :) My textbook has not introduced that class

Comment: Like this in java

        int r = 8*8; 
        int k = 9;
        for (; k < 18; k++) 
        {
                r += 2*k-1;
                printf("%i ", r);
        }

Comment: @mschauer Yes, but that uses multiplication (which OP didn't want to do).

Comment: I guess it's a homework exercise and that is what the teacher meant. Anyway, r += k + k - 1; does it.

Comment: @mschauer Semester has not even begun and I am two chapters ahead attempting practice problems

Comment: No problem, anyway it is allowed to ask homework question, you "include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it", as you did.